# Background Image Value Condition RDLC NAV

Tags: report, rdlc, nav

How can i dynamically change the background image of a header, body or footer on RDLC reports. There is the field value in it but when i do an if condition, RDLC says that he does not recognise the image names.

For example:

```
=iif(Salesperson="Hello",BrevpapirelgrossistenCopy,AnotherPicture)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer since the field is "Value" . I have placed the embedded image name into dounble quotes like:

=iif(Salesperson="Hello","BrevpapirelgrossistenCopy","AnotherPicture")

And it worked!

First i though that it should be called as if it was a data item value. But since you are telling VS studio that it is already an embedded image, then it just go and search for the image name in the embedded image folder.